# What errors would be logged if SSD is failing or has failed in RAID 1?

Tags: linux, ssd, logging

What are the errors, if any, that would be observed on `/var/log/messages` if an SSD is failing or has failed? I would like to know how such errors would be worded so that it could be picked up by an automated program to warn the user to replace the degraded disk before the second one fail.

Comment: How you set up the RAID? Software RAID via mdadm?  Via a hardware RAID card?

Comment: @Hennes, Via Hardware RAID

Comment: @QuestionOverflow What type of hardware RAID controller is being used?

Comment: @ewwhite, wow, that is very specific. I am just asking because I intend to set up such a system, not that I have it now. :p

Comment: With hardware RAID, it depends heavily on which controllers you use. They all report errors differently. Adaptec, HP, LSI, etc.

Comment: Please read our [faq] in particular http://serverfault.com/faq#dontask

Comment: @ewwhite, I see.. But would such errors be reported on `/var/log/messages`, and how does one looks like?

Comment: No, you would not see errors in most cases, but it depends on which controllers you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on:

Your server hardware, storage backplane, OS type, whether you're using a hardware RAID or software RAID, the type of SSD, etc. Are you also looking at S.M.A.R.T. errors?

If hardware RAID, the failure would be reported the same way any disk would. What type of hardware controller is being used?

If software RAID, `mdadm`.

Comment: Yes, I am also looking at SMART via smartmontools, but will anything be shown on `/var/log/messages` if there is a failure? The OS is Fedora 17.